# How to solve W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

i am using java in android studio . When using mi note 8 api-30 i got an error like this .When using any device of api <30 error isn't coming . Why?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please edit your question and add your code snippets, error logs, and any useful information to help others answer your question.